# Which white beans have phosphatidylserine?

Tags: food, nutrition

Many articles online say that plant foods are poor sources of phosphatidylserine, except for white beans, which have 107 mg per 100 g.[¹](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jhn.12090) [²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphatidylserine) [⁴](https://www.livestrong.com/article/289824-foods-that-contain-phosphatidylserine/) Honestly though, I think they might just be repeating a claim from Wikipedia, which cites "Souci SW, Fachmann E, Kraut H (2008). Food Composition and Nutrition Tables. Medpharm Scientific Publishers Stuttgart." I wasn't able to find this source freely available online. Examine.com mentions that "Phosphatidylserine (PS) is found in Soy Lecithin at around 3% of total phospholipids"[⁵](https://examine.com/supplements/phosphatidylserine/#how-to-take), citing https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18846580.

I haven't been able to find any (reliable) sources that say *which* kind of white bean is being referred to here: is it navy beans, cannellini beans, great northern beans, runner beans, or marrow beans? There are some that say navy beans,[³](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy_bean#Other_white_beans), but I believe that information is derived from the Wikipedia article on phosphatidylserine, plus some speculation based on what the writer of the article thinks "white bean" refers to.

Comment: Use sci-hub to get the article? You probably know this by now though since this question is old.